# What is wrong in my file reading with Scanner class?

Tags: java, exception

Every time I run it, gives this message (( InputMismatchException )) where is the problem from ?

```
        File f = new File("nameList.txt");
    try {
        PrintWriter out;
        out = new PrintWriter(f);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            out.printf("Name : %s Age : %d ", "Rezaee-Hadi", 19);
            out.println("");
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception thrown : " + ex);
    }
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(f);
        String name = in.nextLine();
        int age = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(age);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception thrown : " + ex);
    }
```

Comment: in.nextLine() reads until the end of the line. The next token will be "Name" and the programm tries to interpret it as an int for the age-variable.

Comment: What do you enter, how do you enter it, what is the exact stacktrace?

Comment: @Stultuske I want to print all the data in the file

Comment: ok .. and? i'm not really asking about your file, I'm asking about how you enter your data using Scanner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating your data file in the following data format:

```
Name : Rezaee-Hadi Age : 19
```

Now, it really doesn't matter (to some extent) how you format your data file as long as you realize that you may need to parse that data later on. You really don't need to maintain a header with your data on each file line. We already know that the first piece of data on any file line is to be a Name and the second piece of data on any file line is to be the Age of the person the Name relates to. So, the following is sufficient:

```
Rezaee-Hadi, 19
```

If you want, you can place a header as the very first line of the data file so that it can easily be determined what each piece of data on each line relates to, for example:

```
Name, Age
Rezaee-Hadi, 19
Fred Flintstone, 32
Tom Jones, 66
John Smith, 54
```

This is actually a typical format for CSV data files.

> **Keeping with the file data format you are already using:**

There is nothing wrong with using the [Scanner#nextLine()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm) method. It's a good way to go but you should be iterating through the file line by line using a **while** loop because you may not always know exactly how many actual data lines are contained within the file, for example:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(f);
String dataLine;
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    dataLine = in.nextLine().trim();
    // Skip Blank Lines
    if (dataLine.equals("")) {
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println(dataLine);
}
```

This will print all the data lines contained within your file. But this is not what you really want is it. You want to separate the name and age from each line which means then that you need to **parse** the data from each line. One way (in your case) would be something like this:

```
String dataLine;
Scanner in = new Scanner(f);
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    dataLine = in.nextLine().trim();
    // Skip Blank Lines
    if (dataLine.equals("")) {
        continue;
    }
    String[] dataParts = dataLine.replace("Name : " , "").split(" Age : ");
    System.out.println("The Person's Name: " + dataParts[0] + System.lineSeparator() 
                     + "The Person's Age:  " + dataParts[1] + System.lineSeparator());
}
```

In the above code we iterate through the entire data file one line at a time using a **while** loop. As each line is read into the **dataLine** string variable it is also trimmed of any leading or trailing whitespaces. Normally we don't want these. We then check to make sure the line is not blank. We don't normally want these either and here we skip past those blank lines by issuing a **continue** to the while loop so as to immediately initiate another iteration. If the file line line actually contains data then it is held within the **dataLine** variable.

Now we want to parse that data so as to retrieve the Name and the Age and place them into a String Array. We do this by using the [String#split()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) method but first we get rid of the "**Name :** " portion of the line using the [String#replace()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm) method since we don't want to deal with this text while we parse the line. In the [String#split()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) method we supply a string delimiter to split by and that delimiter is " **Age :** ".

```
String[] dataParts = dataLine.replace("Name : " , "").split(" Age : ");
```

Now when each line is parsed, the Name and Age will be contained within the **dataParts[]** string array as elements located at index 0 and index 1. We now use these array elements to display the results to console window.

At this point the Age is a **string** located in the **dataParts[]** array at index **1** but you may want to convert this age to a Integer (int) type value. To do this you can utilize the [Integer.parseInt()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm) or [Integer.valueOf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/integer_valueof_string.htm) methods but before you do that you should validate the fact the the string you are about to pass to either of these methods is indeed a string numerical integer value. To do this you would utilize the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method along with a simple little [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (RegEx):

```
int age = 0;
if (dataParts[1].matches("\\d+")) {
    age = Integer.parseInt(dataParts[1]);
    // OR  age = Integer.valueOf(dataParts[1]);
    System.out.println("Age = " + age);  
}
else {
    System.out.println("Age is not a numerical value!");  
}
```

The regular expression `"\\d+"` placed within the **String#matches()** method basically  means, "Is the supplied string a string representation of a integer numerical value?". If the method finds that it is not then boolean **false** is returned. If it finds that the value supplied is a string integer numerical value then boolean **true** is returned. Doing things this way will prevent any ***NumberFormatException***'s from occurring.

Comment: Very complete and comprehensive Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
        int age=0;
        while (in.hasNext()) {

            // if the next is a Int,
            // print found and the Int
            if (in.hasNextInt()) {
                 age = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Found Int value :"
                        + age);
            }
        }
```

in place of this:

```
  int age = in.nextInt();
```

Then you will not get "InputMismatchException" anymore..